# Access copy row table1 to table 2(İf x=.y to table 2)And if(x=z to table3)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I started to use Microsoft Access and I have a problem now.First of all I will work with 10 000+ rows.As my research true ; it wont be problem while working Access.

And my main question..Wanna copy rows to table1 to other tables. Table1 includes all informations. And copy must work like this.

If Table1 (column7) ''Status''=''Backorder'' copy that row to table2 (created for backorders)

Or if table1 ''Status''=''Ready'' copy that row to table3(created for ready orders)

If you help me I will be so gratefull.Thanks For Help

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy records around, use **queries** for this.

e.g. "table2" =

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Status = "Backorder"
```

You can use this query just like a table, e.g. as record source for a form or report.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it worked.İf other comment dont work I will use queries

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy records in another table then you can do it with vba code.

```
status= "Backorder"
set rs1 =currentdb.OpenRecordset("table2") 
set rs = currentdb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1 where status = '" & status & "'  ")
while not rs.eof

   rs1.addNew

       rs1!cloumnName = rs!colomnName         

   rs1.update

rs.movenext
wend
```